# Не создается таблица sqlite при обновлении приложения

Tags: android, sqlite

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.predmet_zapis);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_predmet);
    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bd = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            String chisl1 = ed1.getText().toString();
            cv.put("chisl", chisl1);
            long rowID = bd.insert("mypoints", null, cv);
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    });
}

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    // конструктор суперкласса
    super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // создаем таблицу с полями
    Log.d("123","cоздана БД");
    db.execSQL("create table mypoints ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "chisl text"+");");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Пытаюсь создать БД, но не создается. Пишет "no such table: mypoints".

Удалил приложение с телефона, заново установил - заработало, но после того как решил поменять название таблицы, перестало работать с той же ошибкой, почему так?

Comment: Ваш Пример не описывает создание БД, а это описаник класса onClick, при нажатии кнопки bt1, в которой реализуется работа с БД а точнее вставка, в таблицу "mypoints" значений из EditText - ed1. А ошибка пишет, что такой таблицы как "mypoints" не существует.

Comment: Удалил приложение с телефона, заново установил заработало, но после того как решил поменять название таблицы, перестало работать с той же ошибкой, почему так?

Comment: В коде нет ошибки. Если вы меняете имя таблицы, вы также должны поменять имя - куда вставляете значение. Иначе будет выскакивать ошибка, что такой таблицы не существует, как у Вас. Выкладывайте код, когда у Вас возникла ошибка, а не когда он был рабочим, сэкономите время себе и другим, ибо искать ошибку там где её нет, порой намного сложнее, чем там, где их достаточно.

Comment: В том то и дело, я выложил код, когда имелась ошибка. Название БД менял в обоих местах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onCreate` вызывается когда нет БД. При обновлении приложения БД уже существует и `onCreate` не вызывается, следовательно новая таблица не создаётся.

Если вы решили изменить структуру БД, то нужно увеличить номер версии БД в вызове родительского конструктора:

```
super(context, "myDB", null, 2);
```

И в функцию `onUpgrade` добавить логику: что делать для приведения старой БД к новой структуре:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL("alter table mytable rename to mypoints;");
    }
}
```

Comment: unUpgrade реализовали? Ошибка та же?

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!)))вылетело из головы, что таблицу нужно переименовывать)

Comment: @roma, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то надо отметить его "верным" - это кнопка-галочка слева от тела вопроса, сразу под стрелками. Также приветствуется голосование за вопрос нажатием стрелочки вверх.

Comment: Если приложение тестовое, а не у пользователей, то проще просто удалить приложение с тестируемого устройства, БД тоже будет удалена и при следующем тестовом запуске создана заново с новой таблицей