# База данных создаваемая на первом Activity и поместить в ListView на втором Activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Есть первое активити,на котором заполняется база данных.
На втором активити ее нужно отобразить в `ListView`.
Что я не так делаю, что здесь лишнее или чего не хватает?
Что прописать во втором классе, чтобы отобразить базу данных во втором активити,
какой объект надо передать? Ничего не получается.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
public Button btnOk;
public EditText tvSum;
public Spinner spinner;
DBHelper dbHelper;
SimpleCursorAdapter cAdapter;
ListView mList;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.zrob);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

    btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mList);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    tvSum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    String[] valuta = {"RU","UA","USD","EUR"};    

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,valuta);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);




    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("Waluta");
    spinner.setSelection(0);




    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  //Объект для данных
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    String suma = tvSum.getText().toString();
    String valuta = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

   //подключаюсь к базе
   SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   // запаковал
    cv.put("suma", suma);
    cv.put("valuta", valuta);



    //Получил id строки
    long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);

    //Получил курсор с данными

    Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    //получаем id столбцов

        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int sumColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("suma");
        int valColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("valuta");


        do {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "id = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) +
                            ", suma = " + c.getString(sumColIndex) +
                            ", valuta = " + c.getString(valColIndex));

                String[] headers = new String[] {"suma","valuta"};
                cAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                         c, headers, new int[]{kontoColIndex, sumColIndex}, 0);
                 mList.setAdapter(cAdapter);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    } else
        Log.d(TAG, "0 rows");

    c.close();


}

class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
        db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "suma text,"
                + "valuta text" +");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Поясните что именно не получается. Возможно, вам не надо курсор закрывать после создания адаптера.

Comment: В вопросе речь о двух активити, но никаких попыток работы со второй активити в коде не присутствует. Что вы имеете в виду, говоря о передаче данных между активити?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Курсор **абсолютно  точно** не надо закрывать, пока список отображается.
Закрывайте курсор либо в методе `onPause()`, но тогда его надо восстанавливать в `onResume()`, либо в `onStop()`, но тогда при определенных обстоятельствах возможно, что этот метод не будет вызван.

Наилучшим решением будет [использовать класс `CursorLoader`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427870/177345) для получения данных в курсор.

Конструкция с назначением адаптера в цикле абсолютно неправильная. Адаптер назначается один раз. При инициализации адаптера ему передается курсор целиком и не надо перебирать все его элементы в цикле, адаптер сам переберет их, когда будет отображать на экране. При этом в адаптер четвертым аргументом (у вас headers) передаются имена столбцов в БД, которые должны отображаться в списке - они должны присутствовать в выборке курсора, пятым аргументом - айдишники View, на айтеме списка (у вас на разметке *layout.two_line_list_item.xml*) в которые эти данные будут помещаться. В данном случае указываются системные айдишники из системной же разметки, которые предопределены заранее (android.R.id.text1 и android.R.id.text2):

```
Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
String[] headers = new String[] {"suma text","valuta text"};
cAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                         c, headers, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
mList.setAdapter(cAdapter);    
//c.close();
```

колонка в БД с айдишниками записей [должна называться *_id*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440080/177345) и никак иначе (у вас *id*) для корректной работы с классами SDK Android^

```
db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
            + "_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "suma text,"
            + "valuta text" +");");
```

подробнее читайте, например, [этот гайд](http://metanit.com/java/android/14.1.php)

О какой второй активити идет речь абсолютно не понятно. В предоставленном коде у вас и данные и список на одной активити и что, куда и кому передать из вопроса решительно не понятно.

Comment: Cursor c = db.query("mytable", new String[]
                {"_id", "suma", "valuta"}, null, null, null, null, null); Изменил "id' на "_id". И в создании базы данных изменил.Но получаю ошибку no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, suma, valuta FROM mytable.

Comment: @Павел Это потому, что база данных уже создана и теперь вы не можете просто так, исправив запрос создания БД, изменить в ней колонки, нужно обновить саму БД через метод `onUpgrade()`. Смотрите подробнее [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466412/177345)

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы отобразить данные во второй Активити, ничего ей передавать не надо. Нужно просто во второй Активити организовать подключение к БД. Для этого нужно открыть БД на чтение:

```
    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper = new DataBaseOpenHelper(this);
    db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase() ;
```

Курсором выбрать нужную информацию, например:

```
cursor = db.query("mytable", new String[]
            {"_id", "suma", "valuta"},null, null, null, null, null);
```

Посредством адаптера разместить полученную информацию в ListView. Для этого в методе onCreate находите нужную Listview и назначаете ей адаптер, например:

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.YourListView);

    cAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                     c, headers, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
```

Не забываем при этом организовать работу с использованием CursorLoader, для того чтобы операции с БД выполнялись не в основном потоке GUI.